# Return substring of a string in php

Tags: php, string, substring

I want to remove string from a string from end.

for example I have a php string variable `"SomeText1|SomeText2|SomeText3|SomeText4|SomeText5|SomeText6"` and i want value `"SomeText1|SomeText2|SomeText3|SomeText4|SomeText5"` in PHP.

I tried using `strrpos()` to get the last occurrence of `"|"` i got index now i am stuck how to process further

Every time i want string excluding the last occurrence of "|" followed by the text.

Comment: explode to an array on the `|`, pop the last value off that array, implode on `|` again.... not rocket science.... just 3 lines of code, and no mathematics required

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Mark Baker's solution is more out of the box than a simple substr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the part after the last `|`:

```
$mystring = "SomeText1|SomeText2|SomeText3|SomeText4|SomeText5|SomeText6";
$strpos = strrpos($mystring, "|");
echo substr($mystring, $strpos);
```

If you want the first part before the last `|`:

```
$mystring = "SomeText1|SomeText2|SomeText3|SomeText4|SomeText5|SomeText6";
$strpos = strrpos($mystring, "|");
$strlength = strlen(substr($mystring, $strpos));
echo substr($mystring, 0, -$strlength);
```

Function reference:
1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of chop().. Refer this
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chop.asp

Comment: chop() is an alias to rtrim().  According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php